# Is there a function in sPacy to get the string given hash?

Tags: spacy

Basically looking for opposite of `spacy.strings.get_string_id()` which does not need to load the language model to get the vocabulary. I tried `StringStore` methods, but you need to add the string first or else you get a "Can't retrieve string for hash 'xxx'" error.

Use case is the hash is serialized then it is unserialized somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you will need to keep a copy of the `StringStore` from the pipeline you used to process your documents in order to look up strings for hashes in the future.

In the end, it's nothing more than a list of strings that have been seen before, either as tokens or annotations, which you can simply re-add to a new `StringStore`.

Comment: Thank you. I might just use the string itself instead of the hash then.